# 'ARResults' object has no attribute 'forecast'

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, arima

I want to use the forecast() function, but it has an error "'ARResults' object has no attribute 'forecast' " How do I resolve this attribute error?

I tried installing the latest version of statsmodel and imported it.

Code written:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AR
# split dataset
X = series.values
train, test = X[1:len(X)-7], X[len(X)-7:len(X)+7]
model = AR(train)
model_fit = model.fit()
forecast = model_fit.forecast()[0]
```

X:

[image]

Error received:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-122-bf247fddf57f> in <module>()
      1 # one-step out-of sample forecast
----> 2 forecast = model_fit.forecast()[0]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\wrapper.py in __getattribute__(self, attr)
     33             pass
     34 
---> 35         obj = getattr(results, attr)
     36         data = results.model.data
     37         how = self._wrap_attrs.get(attr)

AttributeError: 'ARResults' object has no attribute 'forecast'
```

Comment: You need to post more code. How did you make `model_fit`?

Comment: @cfulton I have updated my code, do take a look, thanks!

Comment: The AR model doesn't have a `forecast` method. You can use the ARIMA model instead.